# Unable to Control/Position Pseudo Content Sidebar in CSS

Tags: css, image, position, pseudo-element

I am currently working in a CSS only project. I am still a beginner so I'm running into some issues. Currently I am trying to gain control of scale and position of a pseudo-element that I've added to an aside. I've placed a content url in the element and currently it's residing at the bottom of the page.

I have a relative position on it, and that's about it. I've tried adjusting the margins, top/bottom selectors, transform properties, even using a background-image (however I can never get it appear on the page).

```
.sidebar::before {
  content: url("duotone_splash.png");
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like setting `display: block` on the pseudo element will let you adjust margins and do transforms.

```css
.sidebar::before {
  content: url("http://via.placeholder.com/500x500");
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
  left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: block;
  transform: scale(0.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar"></div>
```